# Custom Directive kills ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I was afraid I wouldn't be able to duplicate but, alas, I can duplicate the failure: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joseym/qgH4y/)

The example is simplified, but is exactly what I'm experiencing.

Basically I have a directive that doesn't use a template, that is manually compiled via `$compile(element.contents())(scope)`.

The purpose of the directive is to just create an isolate scope with unique methods and helpers, to be reused throughout the application in various places.

---

I have an array of objects that I want to loop over with `ngRepeat`, however I cannot get the items to loop.

```
app.directive('myDir', function($compile){
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            migrate: '='
        },
        compile: function(tElement, tAttrs, transclude){

            return function Link(scope, element, attrs){
                scope.testArray = [{name: "1st item"}, {name: "2nd Item"}];
                // even tho it isn't printed, it's still in the scope.
                $compile(element.contents())(scope)
                // so is it just not being bound?
            }

        }
    }
})
```

Comment: I assume you have a good reason to do it like this? Because the example doesn't need custom compilation.

Comment: I've also never seen $compile being used like this. Usually, $compile takes a string html template, compiles it and the resulting DOM is inserted / appended etc. I've never seen $compile compiling existing DOM.

Comment: I do have a reason, the example is just simplified to duplicate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Tracing the code, the scope of the ng-repeat is still set to the scope of your first controller when it runs. So, when you tell it to ng-repeat over "testArray" it has no idea what that is as it was not defined on the first controller's scope.

You can see in this fiddle that it does indeed have access to the first scope, but not the scope of your directive: http://jsfiddle.net/6Ndmp/

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <p>ngRepeat doesn't seem to work...</p>
    <hr>
    <!-- I'm trying to create an isolate scope by passing starting data to the directive.
    This data would then be used to build out directive specific methods and getters... -->    
    <div my-dir migrate="send_to_directive">
        <p>I can print it: <code>{{ testArray | json }}</code></p>
        <p>But looping over it doesn't work...</p>
        <ul>
            <li><strong>Before Loop</strong></li>
            <li ng-repeat="item in send_to_directive">{{ item }}</li>
            <li><strong>After Loop</strong></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Unfortunatly, even tho the data is in the directive I cant seem to return it to the element... -->
</div>
```

So why is the ng-repeat directive linking before your directive? I don't know, but if anyone else does, I'd love to learn.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion. I'm guessing that the compile used in a directive when supplying a template (either via url, or string) has a bit more too it than just a simple `$compile` invocation.

Comment: For now I just ended up creating a template file for the directive. I also noticed that `ng-if` doesn't work, so these core directives have more to them than I originally thought. Would love an actual solution, tho.